# Merging Two Tables with pretty table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, prettytable

After scrapping with beautiful soup,
I have 2 tables :

```
x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ['Titre', 'Price']
```

```
y = PrettyTable()
y.field_names = ['Description']
```

OUTPUT:

```
x = 
+-----------------+ 
| Titre | Price   |       
+-----------------+
| a     |  abc    | 
| b     |  xyz    |
+-----------------


y = 
+-----------------+ 
|   DESCRIPTION   |       
+-----------------+
|       abc       | 
|       xyz       |
+-----------------
```

Desired Output:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+ 
| Titre | Price   |  DESCRIPTION    |        
+-----------------+-----------------+
| a     |  abc    |       abc       |
| b     |  xyz    |       xyz       |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Is it possible to merge them ?

To have something like :

```
z = PrettyTable()
z.field_names = ['Titre', 'Price','Description']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible solution in case of number of rows in "y" should be less or equal to number of rows in "x".
Or you can just switch the "x" "y".**

```
z = PrettyTable()
z_rows = []
counter = 0
for i in x.rows:
    i.extend(y.rows[counter])
    counter += 1
    z_rows.append(i)

field = []
field.extend(x.field_names)
field.extend(y.field_names)

z.field_names = field
z.add_rows(z_rows)
```

Result would look like this:

- *remember: y.rows <= x.rows*

[image]